# PL/SQL syntax for displaying text in return statement

Tags: sql, plsql, syntax-error

I am attempting to get text to display in two spots in my return statement but I am receiving a syntax error.

This works:

```
THEN RETURN p_uName || ' insert text ' || total;
```

However, this is what I want and it doesn't work:

```
THEN RETURN p_uName || ' insert text ' || total 'insert more text';
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: `THEN RETURN p_uName || ' insert text ' || total || ' insert more text';`

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of situation where thinking "like a compiler" is useful:

To do this, read the code `RETURN p_uName || ' insert text ' || total 'insert more text';` one token at a time and work out what the interpreter is supposed to do.

In this case, you are asking it to return the result of an expression. That expression is derived by taking `p_uName` and concatenating the result of the expression `' insert text ' || total 'insert more text'` to it.

That second part is itself another expression, so you have to interpret it to mean to take the string literal `' insert text '` and concatenate the result of the expression `total 'insert more text'` to it.

That appears to be another expression, which when you interpret it seems to be to take the variable `total` and then... what? Ah, we have a missing operator. There's the problem.

Comment: +1 for _thinking like compiler_